# Showing the hyperlinked text

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to use org-mode for organizing information about research papers. Each paper has its own `.org` file. There is also one main `.org` file where the papers are organized in categories.

So, suppose that I have an `.org` file for a paper as follows:

```
- Goldenberg2011CDH
- Goldenberg et al., "The Compressed Differential Heuristic", AAAI 2011
```

In the main `.org` file, I might have:

```
* AAAI
** 2011
- Goldenberg2011CDH
```

Is there a way I can have `org-mode` show the title (i.e. `Goldenberg et el., "The Compressed Differential Heuristic", AAAI`) instead of the key (i.e. `Goldenberg2011CDH`) in such a way that, if the title changes in the paper's `.org` file, then it would be shown updated automatically in the main `.org` file? That is, I am looking for a hyperlink that works sort of like a speadsheet formula -- when the linked cells change, the answer in the formula cell is updated automatically.